# What is the mean of Push in Git?

Tags: git

After I clicked stage changed, I can select commit or push. What is the usage of push? It asked me to select destination repository and source branches. After I do this. Will the other's repository be changed by this push command?

Comment: No, only the repository you're pushing to will be changed, assuming the push is successful.

Comment: Is it same as check out on other's branch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Pushing is how you transfer commits from your local repository to a remote repository (typically the origin).*
The most common use case for [git push](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) is to publish your local changes to a central repository. After you’ve accumulated several local commits and are ready to share them with other users.

Take a look at the image below for a self explanatory schema :

[image: git schema]

As you can see in the picture with a push command you can transfer object from your local repository to a remote repository. The counterpart of a git push is git fetch (or pull that automatically merge) command, that as you can see transfer changes from remote repository to your local repository.

Below you can see what happens when your local master has progressed past the central repository’s master and you publish changes by running `git push origin master` :

[image: git push situation]

### Synthax

```
git push [alias] [branch]
```

Tags aren't automatically pushed when you push a branch, so to push them you have to use the following synthax :

```
git push <remote> --tags
```

Answer (score 2):

In the typical case, push transfers your changes from a cloned repository which you committed to, to the original repository which was cloned

For the general case, see the useful comments to the answer. I am not sure whether the remotes have to be in some way related to the repository you cloned, and if not, how can changes be merged into an arbitrary repository. But I doubt if that's what you are looking to understand, so the typical case should be sufficient.

Comment: push doesn't have to be to the original repository you cloned, it can be to any remote repository

Comment: Technically `push` pushes changes to *any* remote you've configured, not just the default one created when you clone a repository.

Answer (score 1):

Push command does send your commits to a remote repository you have configured.
If you don't have any remote repositories, push command will fail.

This is mainly used so the remote repository can receive commits from many sources and be up to date. In a team of developers, it is normal to pull commits from remote repository so your local project is up to date with the production environment and when you finish your tasks, you push them to update the remote repository.